# Facing some difficulties while trying to only include listed items to append

Tags: python

Trying to make it so that only when options "A","B","C","D" are chosen, then it will be added into the guess list

```
def new_game():
    guesses = []
    choices = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    correct_guesses = 0
    question_number = 1
    guess = []
    for key in questions:
        print("------------------")
        print(key)
        for i in options[question_number - 1]:
            print(i)
        while guess not in choices:
            guess = input('(A, B, C, or D?)').upper()
            correct_guesses += check_answer(questions.get(key), guess)
            if guess in choices:
                guesses.append(guess)
                question_number += 1


    display_score(correct_guesses, guesses)


def check_answer(answer, guess):
    if answer == guess:
        print("CORRECT!")
        return 1
    else:
        print("WRONG!")
        return 0


def display_score(correct_guesses, guesses):
    print("---------")
    print("RESULTS")
    print("---------")
    print("Answers : ", end="")
    for i in questions:
        print(questions.get(i), end=" ")
    print()
    print("Guesses : ", end="")
    for i in guesses:
        print(i, end=" ")
    print()

    score = ((correct_guesses / len(questions)) * 100)

    print("Your score is ", int(score), "%")


def play_again():
    response_choices = ["YES", "NO"]
    response = None
    while response not in response_choices:
        response = input("Do you want to play again? ").upper()
    if response == "YES":
        return True
    else:
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        return False


questions = {"ABC": "A",
             "BCD": "B",
             "CDE": "C",
             "DEF": "D"}
options = [["A.ABC", "B.BCD", "C.CDF", "D.DEF"],
           ["B.BCD", "C.CDF", "D.DEF", "A.ABC"],
           ["C.CDF", "D.DEF", "A.ABC", "B.BCD"],
           ["D.DEF", "A.ABC", "B.BCD", "C.CDF"]]

new_game()

while play_again():
    new_game()
```

However, whenever I input options not within choices, it will immediately end the game once an option within the choices list is selected.

Can someone tell me what's the mistake that I'm making!

Comment: I think you meant to have `guess = []` just inside `for key in questions:`. (Although I would use `guess = None`).

Comment: @quamrana Yes! It does work after having  guess = [] just inside for key in questions: Much thanks! May I know the different uses/advantage between guess = [] and guess = None

Comment: While both values are 'falsey' and neither can be found in 'choices', 'None' is a better fit to mean the user has not made a choice yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
def new_game():
guesses = []
choices = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
correct_guesses = 0
question_number = 1
for key in questions:
    print("------------------")
    print(key)
    guess = None # fix
    for i in options[question_number - 1]:
        print(i)
    while guess not in choices:
        guess = input('(A, B, C, or D?)').upper()
        correct_guesses += check_answer(questions.get(key), guess)
        if guess in choices:
            guesses.append(guess)
            question_number += 1


display_score(correct_guesses, guesses)


def check_answer(answer, guess):
    if answer == guess:
        print("CORRECT!")
        return 1
    else:
        print("WRONG!")
        return 0

def display_score(correct_guesses, guesses):
    print("---------")
    print("RESULTS")
    print("---------")
    print("Answers : ", end="")
    for i in questions:
        print(questions.get(i), end=" ")
    print()
    print("Guesses : ", end="")
    for i in guesses:
        print(i, end=" ")
    print()

    score = ((correct_guesses / len(questions)) * 100)

    print("Your score is ", int(score), "%")

def play_again():
    response_choices = ["YES", "NO"]
    response = None
    while response not in response_choices:
        response = input("Do you want to play again? ").upper()
    if response == "YES":
        return True
    else:
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        return False


questions = {"ABC": "A",
             "BCD": "B",
             "CDE": "C",
             "DEF": "D"}
options = [["A.ABC", "B.BCD", "C.CDF", "D.DEF"],
           ["B.BCD", "C.CDF", "D.DEF", "A.ABC"],
           ["C.CDF", "D.DEF", "A.ABC", "B.BCD"],
           ["D.DEF", "A.ABC", "B.BCD", "C.CDF"]]

new_game()

while play_again():
    new_game()
```

The `guess` variable needs to be defined inside the loop `for key in questions:`, because you need to delete its content before the next iteration. Also `guess = []` defines `guess` as a list, but since you only assign it one item, it is unnecessary.